# How to install command sysupgrade ? (need it for openWRT)

Tags: command-line, networking, software-installation

how do I install command sysupgrade ?

I need this command for to work with openWRT, and want to flash a router
made by TP-Link (Model WR710N).

Thank you. Here is a Link, which shows, why I need command sysupgrade.

https://tlwr710nprojects.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/installation-von-openwrt-auf-dem-tl-wr710n/

Comment: Do you wan to install `sysupgrade` on your `Ubuntu` system? It should be run directly on the router.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - I cannot directly run it on the router. Router is bricked and needs to be flashed new with *factory.bin - This means I would need sysupgrade in ubuntu.

Comment: In this case you have to find a way to *debrick* your router, it's usually done with `tftp`, see here https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.debrick

Comment: @EricCarvalho - Sorry, I realized later that sysupgrade is a specific command of openWRT. I was thinking it would be a general linux command to be installed manually.

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to run `sysupgrade` on your router. You need to `ssh` to it first and then run `sysupgrade`.

Example:

```
user@your-pc:~$ ssh root@router
root@router:~# sysupgrade –v openwrt-ar71xx-generic-tl-wr710n-v1-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin
```

I added the shell prompt to the commands to show on which system they are executed. So, first, on your computer, you open a `ssh` connection to your router. In the example command the router is available as router, you probably need to use your routers IP address or DNS name. After loging in to the router, you can type in the command from the tutorial.

The program `sysupgrade` should already be available on your OpenWrt device (it is on mine).

Comment: Would this work, when router is bricked ? Router belongs to a friend who tried already openWRT to flash on it. But he had choosen wrong package. By this only USB is working but not LAN and not WLAN. This would mean then that ssh is blocked.

Comment: Ok, in that case you are in a whole different kind of trouble. You need to find specific unbrick instructions for this device. This might or might not help: https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr710n#unbrick_tl-wr710n